# Python Initialize a global variable in a loop

Tags: python, scope

I have a rather simple question. I am new to python, and am trying to initialize a variable in a for loop, but I do not wish to execute the code dealing with that variable while still inside the for loop.

```
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "p:", ["PORT="])
    print "getopt called"
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print "getopt: error has occured"
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-p", "--PORT"):
        print "Using TCP port#: " , arg
        TCP_PORT = arg  ###<===== Trying to initialize TCP_PORT

socket.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))    ###<====== TCP_PORT used here
```

I know that in java, you could use class.variable to access things outside of the scope that you are using, is there anyway to accomplish this in python? Thanks in advance!

edit:

I get the following output when run:

```
python cli.py 5003

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli.py", line 25, in <module>
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
NameError: name 'TCP_PORT' is not defined
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.  Your code will work as-is.  You don't need to do anything special to "initialize" a variable; just assign a value to it.  For loops don't create a separate scope, so your assignment will be in the same scope as the `socket.connect` line.

Comment: I am getting: "name 'TCP_PORT' is not defined" when I execute this code. Perhaps it is not a scope issue but an issue with my 'arg' variable

Comment: your problem lies elsewhere - either way you would see the `print "Using TCP port#: " , arg`, and you dont, so the "if" does not fire at all. Shouldn't you run "python cli.py -p 5003" instead?

Comment: Note that the error message doesn't match the code you've shown; it says it is happening in `s.connect`.

Comment: @Greg: As lejlot says, that must be because of some other error, like your `if` test never succeeding.

Comment: @lejlot: Spot on, I was carelessly missing my -p argument. Thank you

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: This is true, however I changed it to socket.connect when posting the code here so you knew what I was calling.

Comment: As this is simply a typo in a command running, not any code related problem I suggest to close this question.